# ggplot showing consolidated stats instead summary breakdown of a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

ggplot is not showing the full summary/grouping stats of a variable, but instead a consolidated number (ie total count) on the variable.

I tried googling and researching to no avail.

```
mydatawlocation %>% 
  group_by(`General Location`) %>% 
  summarise(count_level = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor('General Location'), y = count_level)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

The `General Location` variable has multiple locations eg "East", "West". I want to get a breakdown of total count for each (East/West/etc). Instead my code is churning out "General Location" on x-axis and total count on y-axis, without the breakdown

Comment: It will be much easier to understand your challenge if you can share a sample of the data you're working with, or data that is structurally similar. The best way to do this is using the `dput` command, like `dput(head(mydatawlocation))` and pasting the output of that into your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
mydatawlocation %>% 
group_by(`General Location`) %>% 
summarise(count_level = n()) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(`General Location`), y = count_level)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

I have replaced

```
as.factor('General Location')  # using ''
```

with

```
as.factor(`General Location`) # using ``
```

Comment: Works like magic thanks so much! what wld be the diff btw using ('') and (``) i cant seem to get anything on these?

Comment: (`x`)for variable names (unconventional). 'x' for strings.